# AS3 limit bandwidth or prioritize downloads

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, download, limit, bandwidth-throttling

I'm having multiple downloads in a swf, downloading external data.
Can I limit the download speed of one download thread or prioritize one?

Comment: I have no documentation saying so, but from my experience (professional AIR dev, developing in Flash for ~5 years), I have to say such functionality is not included in AS3. My guess is you would have to write your own version of `URLStream`/`URLLoader` to achieve this.

Comment: I think you can "prioritize" one download thread by not starting other downloads until completion or error on the "prioritized" one.

Comment: @Vesper While that is true, I don't think that is what is being asked. The asker wants multiple, simultaneous downloads with each being given a priority level and an associated weighted percentage of the available bandwidth (think how most Torrent applications behave). I would say that such functionality is not available in Flash.

Comment: @Vesper Is exactly what Josh described, ofc is not a torrent client, but sort of

Answer (score 0):

Flash will download them in the order you ask for them. If you need one first, then ask for that one first.

When running within a browser it is actually the browser that makes the download on behalf of the client container (the client merely requests that the browser does the download). A lot of browsers have restrictions on concurrent file downloads anyway, especially in the same domain, and that is not something you will be able to circumvent with the in-built classes.

My guess is that you could roll your own (or use an [existing client](https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient) as a base) using `Socket` instead of `URLLoader`. This would be a large amount of work though - the browser does a lot of free work for you (SSL, cookies from the current session, gzip, keep-alives etc).